# How to reduce the size of Kendo.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I create a web site in MVC 5. When I hosted it's kendo.min.js file size is 3.67MB. I Tried Both CDN and Static of Kendo js file. But no bigger difference come. MY site performance is at F grad. 47% uses of kendo.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually happening, if you use `kendo.all.min.js`, which, as the name suggests, includes all functionality, widgets and kaboozle.

You can always create your own bundle by just using `kendo.web.min.js` and `kendo.menu.js`, based on your needs.

A good starting point is the documentation here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/scripts/what-you-need

Comment: I have already use custom bundle. Both My Script and Kendo Script are produce 47% uses of site.